# ExoPlayer force quality dash

Tags: android, exoplayer, mpeg-dash, exoplayer2.x

I'm trying to get a video player where I can select the quality of the video. Like Youtube: It selects 'auto' by default but with a switch you can select: 360p, 720p etc.

The 'auto' parts works now using this code:
```

```
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(BANDWIDTH_METER);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getContext(), trackSelector, new DefaultLoadControl());
```

Later on I create a new DashMediaSource.

```
 return new DashMediaSource(uri, buildDataSourceFactory(true),
          new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory), mainHandler, null);
```

So the video is playing now but how do I force a the quality now? So for example when I select 360p I want the player to select that representation.

`<AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
            <Representation bandwidth="954483" codecs="avc1.4d401f" frameRate="525007/17491" height="360" id="VIDEO-1" mimeType="video/mp4" startWithSAP="1" width="640">
                <BaseURL>video360.fmp4</BaseURL>
                <SegmentBase indexRange="914-1425" indexRangeExact="true">
                    <Initialization range="0-913"/>
                </SegmentBase>
            </Representation>
            <Representation bandwidth="2351904" codecs="avc1.4d401f" frameRate="525007/17491" height="720" id="VIDEO-2" mimeType="video/mp4" startWithSAP="1" width="1280">
                <BaseURL>video720.fmp4</BaseURL>
                <SegmentBase indexRange="914-1425" indexRangeExact="true">
                    <Initialization range="0-913"/>
                </SegmentBase>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>`

I've found the [FixedTrackSelection](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/trackselection/FixedTrackSelection.html) and [AdaptationSet](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/dash/manifest/AdaptationSet.html) but I don't come to a solution

Does someone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: The Exoplayer demo actually includes this functionality and there is an overview blog available: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44068596/334402