# Change quality of video streaming in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, iptv

i am creating **IPTV** app. In this use **Exoplayer** for **video streaming** and now requirement is change Quality of video at runtime (Auto, 720p, 1080p, HD) like Youtube.

i have found 2-3 solution but i don't understand how to implement that.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

ExoPlayer will do this automatically if the requirement is simply to match the bitrate/quality to the device capabilities and current network conditions.

If you actually want to allow the user to select it manually, that is also supported using the track selector functionality in Exoplayer2:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44068596/334402

The demo app available in GitHub includes TrackSelector functionality which you can look at and modify as you need - most apps just use the DefaultTrackSelector: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer